# rename table to 'NOW() + old_table_name'

Tags: mysql, rename

is it possible somehow to use the NOW() function or something similar in MYSQL rename table()?

the reason i need this is because instead of dropping old tables straight away we prefer to first rename then to  old_ *date-table-was-taken-ouf-of-use*_ table_name so when we actualy delete it we know how long the table has been 'unavailable'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a dynamic SQL statement and execute that:

```
SET @tablename = 'MyTable';

SELECT @query := CONCAT('RENAME TABLE `', @tablename, '` TO `', 
    CURDATE(), @tablename, '`');

PREPARE STMT FROM @query;
EXECUTE STMT;
```

The `curdate()` function returns the current date as string in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

P.S. You can't execute multi-line statements like this from the Query Browser, but you can put them into a file (for example called `commandfile.sql`) and run them like:

```
mysql -u <user> -p<password> <dbname> < commandfile.sql
```