# Rename Mysql Table name with concat

Tags: mysql, rename, concatenation

In MySQL, I need to rename a table with a suffix which identifies previous month, and I'm trying to do that with this syntax:

```
RENAME TABLE 'myTable' TO CONCAT('myTable',DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y_%m'));
```

F.e: I've table name "customers" and what I want is "customer_2015_04".

The problem is with concat order.

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards,

Comment: Have you considered adding a date column to the table? I'm envisaging nightmares if you ever need to search for a customer in all the tables after anything more than about quarter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741008/rename-table-to-now-old-table-name

Comment: What do you mean by "problem is with concat order"? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to do this using a prepared statement:

```
set @sql = CONCAT('RENAME TABLE myTable TO myTable',
                  DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y_%m')
                 );

prepare s from @sql;

execute s;
```