# How append MySQL table name with today's date in format "-YYYY-MM-DD" with BASH

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, command-line

From the Linux CMD line, how would I append a MySQL table name with today's date in YYYY-MM-DD format. For example, if today's date is 4/13/18, it would change tablename to tablename-2018-04-13.

I believe I'm close with what I've tried after entering mysql from command line:

```
ALTER TABLE database.tablename RENAME database.tablename-$(date +%Y-%m-%d);
```

This generates an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-$(date +%Y-%m-%d)' at line 1
```

Comment: You aren't actually running mysql from the bash shell, you are running the mysql command-line client. it's an app that you are inside of in terminal. So you can't just use shell-level commands (like `date +%Y-%m-%d`), you have to use a DATE function that mysql understands. This is, I think, where you took a wrong turn.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: Re poor design, surely it must seem so, and perhaps it is,  but in this case (and to our defense), as presumably happens for others, we are inheriting issues on the fly. We pull somewhat messy data from an external source. As it updates, we go through a frustratingly manual process to complete and correct the new rows in this imported datafeed. Once this is done, tables are updated to the active database appended with "_new." These 4 renames are to archive existing versions and activate new ones. Like life, 'tis not perfect, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using a bash command substitution inside the MySQL client. That won't work, because SQL doesn't know anything about bash syntax like `$()`.

Another problem is that you must use an identifier, not a string. The name of the table can't be an expression, it has to be fixed in your ALTER statement before it is parsed.

You could do this with PREPARE and EXECUTE:

```
mysql> SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE database.tablename RENAME database.tablename_', DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m%d'));
mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
mysql> EXECUTE stmt;
```

Note I changed your table name, because `-` is a special character in SQL identifiers. You can't normally use a table name that has `-` characters. You can if you put your table name in delimiters. MySQL's delimiters are back-ticks.

```
mysql> SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE database.tablename RENAME database.`tablename-', DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d'), '`');
```

Then prepare and execute like before.

But this is needlessly complex, and you would need to remember to use back-ticks every time you want to use this table in a query.

It's much simpler to avoid using special characters in your table names.

Comment: If I'm reading the OPs question right, they say "after entering mysql from command line", I think they are in the mysql CLI client, not passing queries from the shell via mysql command.

Comment: Then why are they using `$()`? That won't work inside the mysql shell.

Comment: My point exactly. Though on further review, it does look like your approach is the least painful, if done correctly. You can use a string for a table rename, so my solution is bunk.

Comment: I rewrote my answer. This apparently isn't about bash at all.

Comment: And I took your suggestions and ran with them, so I've spent the last 20 minutes trying to figure how to actually do it via bash. Finally got it to work : `mysql -u db_user -p -D dbname -e "ALTER TABLE mytable RENAME \\`mytable-$(date +%Y-%m-%d)\\`;"` Damn backticks.

Comment: Thank you, @Anthony. You had exactly the right idea here. I took everyone off course with my -YYYY-MM-DD appending convention, which wasn't important to the task. I ditched this backticks loaded convention, which simplified the process, arriving at: mysql database -e "ALTER TABLE table RENAME table_$(date +%Y%m%d)"

Answer (score 0):

```
set @sql = CONCAT('RENAME TABLE `tablename` TO tablename', DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y_%m_%d')); 
prepare s from @sql; 
execute s;
```

Updated based on @Anthony's comments. The sql command is tested;

Comment: You should test that before posting it as a solution.

Comment: Now I get another error: ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

Comment: You should then do `use <database-name>` to select it before running the query.

Comment: This won't work. RENAME expects an identifier, not a string. So you can't use CONCAT(). You can achieve this with a prepared statement, as suggested in another answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236515/rename-mysql-table-name-with-concat

Answer (score 0):

All the answers and comments brought me to the answer that worked best for me. I ditched the -YYYY-MM-DD appending convention as it does nothing for me other than create problems, as highlighted by @Bill_Karwin above. This is the simple BASH command, very similar to the comment by @Anthony above, that works for me:

```
mysql database -e "ALTER TABLE table RENAME table_$(date +%Y%m%d)";
```

This renames table to (assuming for example if ran on 4/15/18) table_20180415.